# made an error in uk visa application, what to do?

Tags: visas

While filling the online form, instead of ticking on female, i ticked on male. Though my passport has female written on it. I have made the online payment and have taken the printout. My interview with VFS is in one day.

Comment: I made a similar mistake on my own recent UK visa application - I swapped the month & day of my birthday. This was noticed while I was at my appointment for biometrics and corrected by the operator - so I would imagine your mistake can be easily corrected too.